# Using node.js express, how to serve files from sibling directory

Tags: node.js, express

**Background:** I've tried what feels like every combination of variables but I can't figure out how to get my server.app file to use a sibling directory to call index.htm and other files.  It works fine when it's set up as a subdirectory but I can't figure out how to get this to work as siblings.

**Question:** What is wrong with my file structure or calls in express?

**Folder structure:**

A directory named `www` holds two sub-directories that are siblings.

Directory #1 `www/server/server.js`

Directory #2 `www/html/index.htm`

Inside server.js I include these two commands.

```
app.use(express.static('www'));

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.sendfile('/html/index.htm');
});
```

When I access the root I get this error in my browser.

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/html/index.htm`

Both `www/server/server.js`

and  `www/html/index.htm` exist.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: `var path = require('path'); response.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '../html/index.htm'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename you .htm file to .html.

Even if they are the same express.static wont look for .htm

And then use it like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../html'));

app.get('/',(req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html'));
```